# Sending AVAX on Fuji testnet using MetaMask: "RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address"

Tags: transactions, metamask, sendtransaction, avax, fuji

I am able to manually send some AVAX from one to another wallet on the Fuji testnet using MetaMask. Now I am trying to program it as an on-click button on my dapp as follows:

```solidity
    const transactionParameters = {
      nonce: '0x00', 
      to: '0x799e8fFD836fCA42B95711132884224b89fFe0c3', 
      from: '0x487d77db83349470e1d852cd3c70df6c0fb4036b', 
      value: '1000000000000' 
    };

    async function sendAVAX() {
      const txHash = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params: [transactionParameters],
      });

    }
```

But I keep getting `MetaMask - RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.`. What am I doing wrong here? Much appreciated.